# Vertical Alignment in List column

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have an InfoPath form that a user fills out and in one field they type an email address. The information is collected in a list. All of the columns but Email automatically aligns the standard way. The Email is showing top aligned. I attempted to modify the JSON for the column but it didn't work. Would love some advice please.

A picture is attached that will show what I'm referring to.

[image]

Thanks,
Lisa

Comment: What is the data type of your Referral Email column? Can you please add the JSON code you tried to your question?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below json to change the vertical-align to middle:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "display": "table-cell",
    "text-align": "center",
    "vertical-align": "middle"
   }
}
```